# Android: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT while install app on android 1.5

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I am developing app which bust run on both Android 1.5 and Andoroid 2.x platforms.
When I install it on Android 2.2 all is OK, but on emulator with Android 1.5 I get an error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

What is the problem may be?

**UPD** That is Logcat output:

```
09-26 07:12:22.484: INFO/PackageManager(579): /data/app/vmdl23706.tmp changed; unpacking
09-26 07:12:22.494: DEBUG/installd(557): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/vmdl23706.tmp' ---
09-26 07:12:36.114: ERROR/dalvikvm(1362): LinearAlloc exceeded capacity, last=336
09-26 07:12:36.114: ERROR/dalvikvm(1362): VM aborting
09-26 07:12:36.265: INFO/DEBUG(551): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-26 07:12:36.265: INFO/DEBUG(551): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:1.5/CUPCAKE/150240:eng/test-keys'
09-26 07:12:36.265: INFO/DEBUG(551): pid: 1362, tid: 1362  >>> /system/bin/dexopt <<<
09-26 07:12:36.265: INFO/DEBUG(551): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadd00d
```

It seems that memory was not enough... If anybody knows how to fight with such problem? I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Maybe could be a problem of the number of classes/methods of the App. I commeted also in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25595353/2411379

Answer (score 5):

It's a limitation in Dalvik triggered on unusually complex interface hierarchies.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22586

See the details for ideas on working around. Simple answer might be to try using different libraries that are less complex.

A fix has been merged into Android AOSP. 
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/30900/

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to install my app on the emulator. What helped was to reset the emulator (wipe all user data) via AVD Manager. Let's see how long this will last....