# INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT error when trying to install application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat, android-install-apk

I have a similar problem to the ones listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153515/how-to-solve-install-failed-dexopt-this-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776152/android-install-failed-dexopt-while-install-app-on-android-1-5).

I am getting an INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT error every time I try to install my app on my Motorola Xoom.

Here is the error message from the console:

```
[2011-08-02 09:34:43 - Blade] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT
[2011-08-02 09:34:43 - Blade] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-08-02 09:34:43 - Blade] Launch canceled!
```

And here is the corresponding logcat:

```
08-02 09:47:48.910: ERROR/PackageManager(142): Package com.theisenp.blade has mismatched uid: 10023 on disk, 10073 in settings
08-02 09:47:48.910: INFO/PackageManager(142): Linking native library dir for /data/app/com.theisenp.blade-1.apk
08-02 09:47:49.110: ERROR/dalvikvm(2094): Duplicate interface: 'Lgnu/trove/TIntIntProcedure;'
08-02 09:47:49.110: ERROR/dalvikvm(2094): Trouble with item 1108 @ offset 0x5d49c
08-02 09:47:49.110: ERROR/dalvikvm(2094): Cross-item verify of section type 0006 failed
08-02 09:47:49.110: ERROR/dalvikvm(2094): ERROR: Byte swap + verify failed
08-02 09:47:50.140: ERROR/dalvikvm(2094): Optimization failed
08-02 09:47:50.150: WARN/installd(91): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.theisenp.blade-1.apk' --- status=0xff00, process failed
08-02 09:47:50.150: ERROR/installd(91): dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.theisenp.blade-1.apk@classes.dex' res = 65280
08-02 09:47:50.160: WARN/PackageManager(142): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.theisenp.blade-1.apk
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Selecting the "Wipe User Data" option in the Run Configurations -> Target menu.  (Though I can only see emulators and not my physical device in this tab.  Perhaps I'm not actually wiping user data from the Xoom?)
- Uninstalling the app from my device before trying to reinstall
- Restarting the device multiple times

Any suggestions you can offer are very much appreciated!

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling the app works in most cases. Question is, Is there a better and quicker option?

Comment: @ChandraMohan that is NOT true. Stop trying to make it true. I've formatted my device and tried to re-install the app. It still throws this error!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to uninstall this app, and all others who have your signature on your device (your other apps). Clean your project and restart install. Also, you should consider installing your app through another mean that ADB, for instance using dropbox.

Comment: I was just in the process of answering my own question after accidentally fixing the problem on my own, but you seem to have beaten me to it.  I uninstalled all of my own apps from the device and re-cleaned the project, and everything appears to be working normally.  Thanks!

Comment: No this is not helped me! I dont have my own apps on device cleaned project and tried to install but no luck.

Comment: What is really sad about your answer is that you are right. Wipping data made the app to be installed.

Answer (score 24):

I didn't have any previous version of the App installed, so uninstall was not an option. On newer version of Emulator you can fix that by doing **Cold boot** in AVDM (Android Virtual Device Manager), that had helped me.

[image: Place Where you can find cold boot]

Answer (score 3):

you can also try out wipe user data option when starting emulator.This worked for me.The reason  behind this error is you are not updating your emulator with the application data that is already changed.So emulator can't find the new data in your installed application.hope this will work for you.

Comment: The OP stated that they have already tried 'Selecting the "Wipe User Data" option in the Run Configurations -> Target menu.'

Answer (score 2):

I suggest running Eclipse and viewing LogCat output to see what the actual error message is. I was getting this error and it was because my device was low on storage and it was failing to unzip the APK. I believe there are multiple reasons that this error can be triggered and uninstalling or clearing user data may be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Me faced similar error when device memory was almost utilized, was able to resolve by removing some files. So please check if enough free space is available in your device memory

Answer (score 0):

I had "Manage App Permissions" enabled, after disabling I could install app using adb

Comment: where is the option to enabled?