# Unable install app into emulator 2.3.3 : INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT

Tags: android, android-emulator

I use the latest `adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130717`, with

- Android SDK Tools - 22.0.4
- Android SDK Platform-tools - 18

I had tried to install app on emulator 2.3.3, both for ARM and Intel. However, it no longer work **(It used to work in my same Win64 machine before I'm using latest adt)**

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!
```

My emulator setting is as follow.

[image]

I had followed [how to solve INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153515/how-to-solve-install-failed-dexopt-this-error). It doesn't help for my case.

Note that, emulator with 4.1.2 work extremely well for Intel. I even try to email the APK, and download -> install from emulator. But, this is what I'm getting `Application not installed`

[image]

Any workaround to overcome this problem?

My logcat is having such logging

```
E/PackageManager(855): Package org.yccheok.jstock.gui has mismatched uid: 10031 on disk, 10033 in settings
E/dalvikvm(1241): LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=468
E/dalvikvm(1241): VM aborting
E/installd(798): dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@org.yccheok.jstock.gui-1.apk@classes.dex' res = 11
```

Note, the problem will not occur, if I were using emulator 4.1.2

Comment: What does `logcat` say?

Comment: Not really. I accept it as I see it might be helpful to others. But not me. I end up using emulator from Android Studio. Not convenient, as my project is in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to find out what the error is from the information you provided.

Try the following

- Clean your project
- Uninstall your app
- Download a different version of adt bundle
- Experiment with different emulators with different values
- Try to use a real device, does the problem still occur?
- Look through these links, maybe your problem is similar:
- http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2009/05/25/android-fix-package-uid-mismatches/
- [How to solve Installation failed due to invalid APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532044/how-to-solve-installation-failed-due-to-invalid-apk-file)
- [LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=1092 Error while installing on my Samsung Tablet Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413898/linearalloc-exceeded-capacity-5242880-last-1092-error-while-instaling-on-my-s)
- [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT error when trying to install application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913230/install-failed-dexopt-error-when-trying-to-install-application)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time associated with excessive values for LinearAlloc. Putting verbose mode for logcat could give you more details (can even pinpoint the problem). 
There no definite fix I heard of.Sometimes it can be fixed by wiping AVD, some get fix by increasing SD card only, some had to recreate new AVD, some fixed it by reinstalling ADT, there are lots of fixes people speak of, answer can be varied as actual problem.

Sometimes problem can be  corrupted files, or application install entries which makes android confused whether app is installed or not. Or by use of complex libraries, or even problem with the compiler itself.
 There's not a lot of clear information on this error from Google, they say it is related to a bug in Android OS that doesn't frees files handles in some cases. However as looking to logcat it always connected to some dex files. and so as to DDMS and compiler.
I suggest you to try all of the fixes I stated, also refer the given links
[Issue 22586:   Dexopt fails with "LinearAlloc exceeded" for deep interface hierarchies](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22586)

[Cleanup redundant interfaces from iftable to avoid excessive LinearAlloc use](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/30900/)

[Issue 42538:   INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT solved by dex.disable.merger=true](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42538)

If everything failed please put your verbose logcat

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling your app before installing it again. It seems to have solved the issue for some according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913230/install-failed-dexopt-error-when-trying-to-install-application)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue after upgrading ADT and I was stuck for this issue for almost half and a day.After every HIT and TRY method found the solution.

**

> ONE OF LIBRARY PROJECT BUILD TARGET WAS HIGHER THEN MY PROJECT , JUST
>   CHANGED LIBRARY PROJECT BUILD TARGET TO 3.0 AND MY PROJECT BUILD
>   TARGET TO 4.0.3 AND IT VANISHES.

**

Just posted my solution if it helps others in future.

Comment: thanks for you advice (not helped for me, but leads to solution). 
I have to UNCHECK PRE-DEX EXTERNAL JARS...DEPENDENCIES.

I use IntelliJ Idea, if you stranger too - go to Project Structure - Modules - Packaging