# dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/

Tags: android

I developed an application in Android but I cant install it in my phone. Error says:

```
installd > dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.lee-1.apk@classes.dex' res = 11
```

Im currently using Cherry Mobile (Android 2.3). How to fix this one?

Comment: Have u tried clean the project and run again?

Comment: I tried it already but it didn't work!

Comment: Is that device have enough space  to install that app?

Comment: Maybe duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889374/unable-install-app-into-emulator-2-3-3-install-failed-dexopt