# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT on Samsung S device

Tags: android

I've tried to run a project from eclipse on samsung s device, 
i got `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT`

But i tried to run on other device Samsung S4, its installed successfully.

i've tried the like mention on below thread

[INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT error when trying to install application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913230/install-failed-dexopt-error-when-trying-to-install-application)

i've uninstalled all app. and cleaned the project on eclipse. but still i got error.

I've reset my phone too. but still the problem i have.

Where is the exact problem. in phone ? or eclipse project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced same problem.

Please check your library folder if you are using any http client and http mime library, remove http client library.

Its working for me after removing that library on 2.3 devices.

Comment: Only library in my project is ksoap2. I do not cut my hand if there is little infection on my finger. So any solution without removing library?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal I think it is one of those 64K method limit. Some dependencies will have to make way.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal if you are, like me, using IJKPlayer you'd have to remove exo-player dependency.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was Google's Guava library that created the problem, removed it from my \libs folder and it all worked out.