# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]

Tags: android, android-studio

When i upload my app in virtual device i have a problem, how fix it?
Virtual device: Nexus S, CPU: Intel Atom x86. I am use Android Studio

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: emulator-5554
Uploading file
    local path: D:\git\Genius\app\build\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.vlad.genius.app
Installing com.vlad.genius.app
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.vlad.genius.app"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.vlad.genius.app
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

I running virtual device with wipe user data, but it is don`t help me.

In Logcat i see that line:

```
05-04 16:44:49.940    1775-1775/? W/dalvikvm﹕ DexOptZ: zip archive '/data/app/com.vlad.genius.app-1.apk' does not include classes.dex
05-04 16:44:49.940      956-956/? W/installd﹕ DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.vlad.genius.app-1.apk' --- status=0xff00, process failed
05-04 16:44:49.940      956-956/? E/installd﹕ dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.vlad.genius.app-1.apk@classes.dex' res = 65280
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153515/how-to-solve-install-failed-dexopt-this-error

Comment: @mocialov-boris it`s don`t help me

Comment: It helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702494/installation-error-install-failed-dexopt-on-samsung-s-device

Comment: First, you should probably not be trying to deploy the **unaligned** apk file on the device.  But given the error message, you should open the .apk file as if it were a zip file and see if it actually contains a classes.dex - if not it will not work, and you need to figure out what is broken about the build process.

Comment: did you find out a solution please ? I have the same problem ...

Comment: @ahmed_khan_89 I make a new app and copy all logic

Comment: Have you recently updated your build tools in android studio?

Answer (score 4):

The most common cause of the problem is dex limits on android. There are two kinds of limit, first on the number of methods that you can have and second around the cache size (in a way directly related)

Google documents this problem here : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22586

So the first question would be which android version are you trying to install. Then use the dexdump tool (in build-tool in android SDK) and find out the number of methods you have.