# Eclipse compile android project cannot start

Tags: android

In the console, it prompts the error

```
[2014-07-24 11:11:57 - Trade] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT
[2014-07-24 11:11:57 - Trade] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-07-24 11:11:57 - Trade] Launch canceled!
```

However, it can install to my handset, just cannot auto start the app. Any suggestion?

Comment: 1) Post the logcat output. 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153515/how-to-solve-install-failed-dexopt-this-error 3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913230/install-failed-dexopt-error-when-trying-to-install-application

Comment: Uninstall old version of your app & add fresh installer of it