# How to avoid LinearAlloc Exceeded Capacity error android

Tags: android, eclipse

The application gets crashing every-time, when am running eclipse saying

**LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=208**

This is happening, when am creating AsyncTask, thats strange this is happening everytime .
when am commenting and running its running.

Logcat is:

```
    02-09 04:02:23.374: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/apache/http/HttpEntityEnclosingRequest;'
    02-09 04:02:23.374: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;'

    02-09 04:02:23.378: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/net/QuotedPrintableCodec;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.378: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/net/StringEncodings;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.378: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/net/URLCodec;': multiple definitions

    02-09 04:02:23.394: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;'
    02-09 04:02:23.397: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/net/URLCodec;'

    02-09 04:02:23.487: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl;'
    02-09 04:02:23.487: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.487: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/NoOpLog;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.487: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog$1;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.487: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.581: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/ConnectionClosedException;': multiple definitions
  /http/StatusLine;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.581: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/TokenIterator;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.581: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/UnsupportedHttpVersionException;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.581: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/auth/AUTH;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.581: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/auth/AuthScheme;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.581: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/auth/AuthSchemeFactory;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.581: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/auth/AuthSchemeRegistry;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.581: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/auth/AuthScope;': multiple definitions

    02-09 04:02:23.589: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.589: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/ConnectionPoolTimeoutException;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.589: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/EofSensorInputStream;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.589: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/HttpHostConnectException;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.589: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/ManagedClientConnection;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.589: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/MultihomePlainSocketFactory;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.589: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/OperatedClientConnection;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.589: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/params/ConnConnectionParamBean;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.589: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/params/ConnManagerParamBean;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.589: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/params/ConnPerRoute;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.589: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/conn/params/ConnManagerParams$1;': multiple definitions

    02-09 04:02:23.597: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRequestDirector;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.597: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultTargetAuthenticationHandler;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.597: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultUserTokenHandler;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.597: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/RequestWrapper;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.597: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.597: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase;'
    02-09 04:02:23.597: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/RedirectLocations;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.597: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/RoutedRequest;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.597: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/TunnelRefusedException;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.597: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/impl/conn/AbstractClientConnAdapter;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.597: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/impl/conn/AbstractPoolEntry;': multiple definitions

    02-09 04:02:23.608: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/protocol/ResponseServer;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.608: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/protocol/SyncBasicHttpContext;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.608: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/protocol/UriPatternMatcher;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.608: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/util/ByteArrayBuffer;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.608: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/util/CharArrayBuffer;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.608: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/util/EncodingUtils;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.608: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/util/EntityUtils;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.608: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/util/ExceptionUtils;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.608: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/util/LangUtils;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.608: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/apache/http/util/VersionInfo;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:23.608: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;'
    02-09 04:02:23.612: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;'
    02-09 04:02:23.612: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;'
    02-09 04:02:23.612: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;'
    02-09 04:02:23.616: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;'

    02-09 04:02:24.312: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
    02-09 04:02:24.312: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
    02-09 04:02:24.312: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
    02-09 04:02:24.312: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
    02-09 04:02:24.312: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
    02-09 04:02:24.312: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
    02-09 04:02:24.312: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
    02-09 04:02:24.312: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;'
    02-09 04:02:24.315: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.315: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlParser;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.315: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.315: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.315: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.315: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Document;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.315: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Element;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.315: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/Wbxml;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.315: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/WbxmlParser;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.315: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/WbxmlSerializer;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.315: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/syncml/SyncML;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.315: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/wml/Wml;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.315: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/kxml2/wap/wv/WV;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.323: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;'
    02-09 04:02:24.398: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;'
    02-09 04:02:24.398: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
    02-09 04:02:24.398: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
    02-09 04:02:24.398: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
    02-09 04:02:24.398: I/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not resolving ambiguous class 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;'
    02-09 04:02:24.495: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.495: D/dalvikvm(3351): DexOpt: not verifying 'Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory;': multiple definitions
    02-09 04:02:24.612: E/dalvikvm(3351): LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=208
    02-09 04:02:24.612: E/dalvikvm(3351): VM aborting
    02-09 04:02:24.640: D/dalvikvm(3307): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 18195 objects / 1125640 bytes in 287ms
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/SGH-T849/SGH-T849/SGH-T849:2.2/FROYO/UVJJB:user/release-keys'
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372): pid: 3351, tid: 3351  >>> /system/bin/dexopt <<<
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadd00d
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  r0 00000026  r1 afd14921  r2 afd14921  r3 00000000
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  r4 800a13f4  r5 800a13f4  r6 004fffa4  r7 000000d0
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  r8 00000000  r9 00000000  10 00000000  fp 00000000
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  ip deadd00d  sp beade740  lr afd1596b  pc 80042078  cpsr 20000030
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d0  643a64696f72646e  d1  6472656767756265
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d2  410be43800000067  d3  00000000410c080a
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d4  6c706d49746e6569  d5  74746977744c293b
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d6  746e692f6a347265  d7  74682f6c616e7265
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d8  0000003108f12b80  d9  0000000000000000
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d16 0000000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
    02-09 04:02:24.745: I/DEBUG(2372):  scr 00000000
    02-09 04:02:24.757: I/DEBUG(2372):          #00  pc 00042078  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.757: I/DEBUG(2372):          #01  pc 00049f40  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.757: I/DEBUG(2372):          #02  pc 00067998  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.757: I/DEBUG(2372):          #03  pc 00067dba  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.757: I/DEBUG(2372):          #04  pc 00068612  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.757: I/DEBUG(2372):          #05  pc 00068846  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.757: I/DEBUG(2372):          #06  pc 0006806a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.757: I/DEBUG(2372):          #07  pc 00057a0c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.757: I/DEBUG(2372):          #08  pc 00057fe6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.757: I/DEBUG(2372):          #09  pc 00053d1e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.757: I/DEBUG(2372):          #10  pc 000566d4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372):          #11  pc 000576c0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372):          #12  pc 00057948  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372):          #13  pc 0005a1f4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372):          #14  pc 0005a25c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372):          #15  pc 0005a32a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372):          #16  pc 000590f2  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372): code around pc:
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372): 80042058 20061861 f7d418a2 2000eb8e ece6f7d4 
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372): 80042068 58234808 b1036bdb f8df4798 2026c01c 
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372): 80042078 0000f88c ed4cf7d4 0005f3a0 fffe300c 
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372): 80042088 fffe6280 0000039c deadd00d f8dfb40e 
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372): 80042098 b503c02c bf00490a 188ba200 f853aa03 
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372): code around lr:
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372): afd15948 b5f74b0d 490da200 2600189b 585c4602 
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372): afd15958 686768a5 f9b5e008 b120000c 46289201 
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372): afd15968 9a014790 35544306 37fff117 6824d5f3 
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372): afd15978 d1ed2c00 bdfe4630 0002c9d8 000000d8 
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372): afd15988 b086b570 f602fb01 9004460c a804a901 
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372): stack:
    02-09 04:02:24.761: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade700  410e9e18  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/0 (deleted)
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade704  410e9e18  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/0 (deleted)
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade708  afd425a0  /system/lib/libc.so
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade70c  afd4254c  /system/lib/libc.so
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade710  00000000  
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade714  afd1596b  /system/lib/libc.so
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade718  afd14921  /system/lib/libc.so
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade71c  afd14921  /system/lib/libc.so
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade720  afd14978  /system/lib/libc.so
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade724  800a13f4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade728  800a13f4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade72c  004fffa4  
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade730  000000d0  
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade734  afd14985  /system/lib/libc.so
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade738  df002777  
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade73c  e3a070ad  
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372): #00 beade740  00016810  [heap]
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade744  80049f45  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372): #01 beade748  000000d0  
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade74c  000fc750  [heap]
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade750  0050007c  
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade754  00000004  
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade758  00016814  [heap]
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade75c  afd0c9c3  /system/lib/libc.so
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade760  42978eee  /system/framework/core.odex
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade764  42978efe  /system/framework/core.odex
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade768  410e9e18  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/0 (deleted)
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade76c  00000000  
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade770  00000004  
    02-09 04:02:24.765: I/DEBUG(2372):     beade774  8006799d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    02-09 04:02:25.129: I/DEBUG(2372): dumpmesg > /data/log/dumpstate_app_native.log
    02-09 04:02:25.218: I/dumpstate(3355): begin
    02-09 04:02:25.253: I/dalvikvm(2495): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-09 04:02:25.276: I/dalvikvm(2495): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-09 04:02:25.444: I/dalvikvm(2593): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-09 04:02:25.452: I/dalvikvm(2593): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-09 04:02:25.460: I/dalvikvm(2598): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-09 04:02:25.464: I/dalvikvm(2598): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-09 04:02:25.480: I/dalvikvm(2601): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-09 04:02:25.487: I/dalvikvm(2601): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-09 04:02:25.503: I/dalvikvm(2655): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-09 04:02:25.526: I/dalvikvm(2655): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-09 04:02:25.703: I/dalvikvm(2676): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-09 04:02:25.851: I/dalvikvm(2708): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-09 04:02:25.855: I/dalvikvm(2676): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-09 04:02:25.866: I/dalvikvm(2746): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-09 04:02:25.886: I/dalvikvm(2746): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-09 04:02:25.901: I/dalvikvm(2753): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-09 04:02:25.905: I/dalvikvm(2753): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-09 04:02:26.097: I/dalvikvm(2795): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-09 04:02:26.315: I/dalvikvm(2850): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
```

am using jaxab-xalan-1.5 jar in referenced libraries. 
How to avoid this Linearalloc exceeded capacity error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I recently hit this problem and my solution was to write wrappers for the library jar and include it in the assets directory.
I also wrote a blog post explaining it with a sample project on github. Hope it helps.
http://birbit.com/how-to-solve-linearalloc-problem/

Comment: I tried to follow your example, but ran into some trouble. It builds an APK file, and it appears to have made two different .dex files, but when I install the app, I get `ClassDefNotFound` errors for the jars that would normally be automatically included and exported by Eclipse. Is there something different I need to do when installing? Do I need to modify the ANT .build file to include jars in /libs somehow?

Comment: Never mind. It was failing on jars that were normally included by Maven. I accounted for that, and it's working great. Thank you so much for that writeup!

Comment: LOVE YOU !!! Thanks, I just didn't use a jar but a library and it solved it for me

Answer (score 3):

It's a limitation in Dalvik triggered on unusually complex interface hierarchies.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22586

See the details for ideas on working around. Simple answer might be to try using different libraries that are less complex.

A fix has been merged into Android AOSP. 
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/30900/

Answer (score 1):

In Android 2.3.x I have this error. I don't know for sure if it's because the number of classes/methods of the App, or because complex hierarchy that I have that. I get rid of the source of Glide library and the error gone away. 
If I remember right, this library has working well in previous releases of my App, before I have grow up in class/method size.

Here make me think it would be the reason:

https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-android/issues/40#issuecomment-45190437